vuetify and moncao-editor css conflicts
When I use Vuetify for development, using moncao-editor, style overrides will appear:
import 'vuetify/styles'


If I comment out vuetify styles
//import 'vuetify/styles'


Please tell me how to resolve the conflict.
I want to display the shadow slash correctly.

The reason was found, it was caused by vuetify’s css reset.
file path :  node_modules/vuetify/lib/styles/generic/_reset.scss
::after {
      background-repeat: no-repeat; /* Set `background-repeat: no-repeat` to all elements and pseudo elements */
      box-sizing: inherit;
    }

You can try commenting out this code to debug. After debugging, make in-depth modifications where third-party files are introduced.
:deep(.monaco-editor .diagonal-fill) {
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

At this point, the problem is solved
